# ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name=main-nav is not working

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I do have angular 6, even though `ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name home` isn't working

got the errors like
`Collection "@angular/material" cannot be resolved.
Error: Collection "@angular/material" cannot be resolved.
    at NodeModulesEngineHost._resolveCollectionPath (/Users/mac/angular/retroAngular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/node-module-engine-host.js:88:15)
    at NodeModulesEngineHost.createCollectionDescription (/Users/mac/angular/retroAngular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/file-system-engine-host-base.js:106:27)
    at SchematicEngine._createCollectionDescription (/Users/mac/angular/retroAngular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:78:40)
    at SchematicEngine.createCollection (/Users/mac/angular/retroAngular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:71:43)
    at Object.getCollection (/Users/mac/angular/retroAngular/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/schematics.js:28:31)
    at GenerateCommand.getOptions (/Users/mac/angular/retroAngular/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:193:41)
    at GenerateCommand.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/angular/retroAngular/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:38:53)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/mac/angular/retroAngular/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)`

Comment: i used this command also : ng add @angular/material@6.2.1 , but it stuck after some extract:@angular/material: verb lock using this...

Answer (score 3):

I have just encounter this problem after upgrading to the latest versions of angular core, angular cli. Solution is  `ng generate @angular/material:material-nav` and then you will be prompted to enter the component name.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you didn't add @angular/material to your node modules yet. Use `ng add @angular/material` first to install @angular/material, and then try to generate a component

Answer (score 0):

It should be `ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name=home` After name you should put = then name

Comment: It should work in your case

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error. But using command **ng g @angular/material:material-nav** separately without component name worked.

```
***Command***
ng g @angular/material:material-nav
***Output***
? What should be the name of the component? main-nav
CREATE src/app/main-nav/main-nav.component.html (934 bytes)
CREATE src/app/main-nav/main-nav.component.spec.ts (1270 bytes)
CREATE src/app/main-nav/main-nav.component.ts (598 bytes)
CREATE src/app/main-nav/main-nav.component.scss (193 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (1060 bytes)
```

[Added Image for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F18QT.png)